# How to matrix map a function

Tags: list-manipulation

I basically want to do this:

```
Function[{t}, f[t, #] & /@ {r1, r2, r4}] /@ {t1, t2, t3}
```

> {{f[t1, r1], f[t1, r2], f[t1, r4]}, {f[t2, r1], f[t2, r2], 
>     f[t2, r4]}, {f[t3, r1], f[t3, r2], f[t3, r4]}}

I imagine there might be a more elegant way I might have missed, by mapping the matrix `{{r1, r2, r4}, {t1, t2, t3}}` directly onto the function `f` without the need of introducing 2 nested pure functions?

Comment: `Outer[f, {t1, t2, t3}, {r1, r2, r4}]`

Comment: thats it. I always saw `Outer` only as the outer matrix product so far. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Partition[(f @@@ Tuples[{{r1, r2, r3}, {t1, t2, t3}}]), 3]
```

but b3m2a1's solution is better...